# Cannot install Rgdal

Tags: r

I am trying to install the rgdal in R 4.3.1

```
Error when I try to install normally

> install.packages("rgdal", dependencies=TRUE,repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rgdal’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

So I tried to build and install from source which when installing this Error pops up

```
> install()
── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\SPB_Data/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'rgdal': (7.2s)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
E  checking vignette meta-information ... 
   Output(s) listed in 'build/vignette.rds' but not in package:
     'inst/doc/CRS_projections_transformations.html'
     'inst/doc/PROJ6_GDAL3.html'
     'inst/doc/OGR_shape_encoding.pdf'
   Run R CMD build without --no-build-vignettes to re-create
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Type .Last.error to see the more details.
```

Then I put in ".Last.error" and output this:

```
> .Last.error
<system_command_status_error/rlib_error_3_0/rlib_error/error>
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Backtrace:
 1. devtools::install()
 2. pkgbuild::build(pkg$path, dest_path = tempdir(), args = build_opts, …
 3. pkgbuild:::withr_with_makevars(compiler_flags(debug = FALSE), { …
 4. pkgbuild:::withr_with_envvar(c(R_MAKEVARS_USER = makevars_file), { …
 5. base::force(code)
 6. base::force(code)
 7. pkgbuild:::withr_with_temp_libpaths(rcmd_build_tools(options$cmd, c(options$path, …
 8. base::force(code)
 9. pkgbuild::rcmd_build_tools(options$cmd, c(options$path, options$args), …
10. pkgbuild::with_build_tools({ …
11. pkgbuild:::withr_with_path(rtools_path(), code)
12. base::force(code)
13. base::withCallingHandlers(callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env, spinner = FALSE, …
14. callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env, spinner = FALSE, show = FALSE, …
15. callr:::run_r(options)
16. base::with(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, …
17. base::with.default(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, …
18. base::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
19. base::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
20. callr:::with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs, …
21. base::force(code)
22. base::do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callb…
23. (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …
24. base::throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo, …
25. | base::signalCondition(cond)
26. (function (e) …
27. asNamespace("callr")$err$throw(e)
>
```

Comment: The package is retired. This is known since very long, see e.g. https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html

Comment: Okay but I need to use code using this package for my research the precious study used this package from 2022 so I assume there must be a way to get it working?

Comment: I can't exactly tell from the trace why it's not working. I know that when I did it on my Mac, it worked: `remotes::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz", type="source")`

Comment: What if you tried installing a binary you could download from the wayback machine.  If you click on [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220807073258/https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/rgdal_1.5-32.zip) the regal 1.5-32 windows binary should download.

Comment: Thank you DaveArmstrong for some reason it worked when I did that! Big help I was getting worried about my research project

Answer (score 1):

If you switch your project's package repository to [Posit Public Package Manager](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/) , you can use snapshots from specific dates.
For example, the first snapshot of October 2023 still includes `rgdal`:

```
"https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-03"
```

https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/setup helps you configure the repository URL.

I'd personally set up a project with `renv` for this:

```r
> renv::init(repos = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-03")
> getOption("repos")
                                             CRAN 
"https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-03" 
> install.packages("rgdal")
# Downloading packages -------------------------------------------------------
- Downloading rgdal from CRAN ...               OK [36.6 Mb in 47s]
- Downloading sp from CRAN ...                  OK [2 Mb in 5.1s]
Successfully downloaded 2 packages in 65 seconds.

The following package(s) will be installed:
- rgdal [1.6-7]
- sp    [2.1-0]
These packages will be installed into "C:/Users/user/tmp/rgdal/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32".

Do you want to proceed? [Y/n]: y

# Installing packages --------------------------------------------------------
- Installing sp ...                             OK [installed binary and cached in 0.87s]
- Installing rgdal ...                          OK [installed binary and cached in 2.3s]
Successfully installed 2 packages in 3.3 seconds.
> rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()
          GDAL GDAL_with_GEOS           PROJ             sp 
       "3.6.2"         "TRUE"        "9.2.0"        "2.1-0"
```